# Why most appliances in US don't have third prong

Tags: ac, ground

Most other plugs I encountered have three prongs - hot, neutral and ground I assume. For example all BS 1363 plugs have one. Also CEE 7/7 have ground connections and while CEE 7/16 exists it is not used for high-power appliances such as computers.

On the other hand I might have seen once grounded NEMA plug even for computers etc. What reasons are there for those differences (is it due to 120 V vs. 240V)?

Comment: Live, neutral and earth. It's likely, I'd guess, that one reason for items like laptops, is that they are made of plastic, so risk of electrocution by a wire touching a case is eliminated. It won't be anything to do with 120/230V as in the UK we have some devices that only use the figure of eight leads that don't carry earth.

Comment: 1) Isolation 2) Polarization

Comment: If you look on the plug you should find a symbol " a square within a square" this means it is "double insulated" i.e. it has two layers of insulation between you and the conductor and therefore, under a certain power, does not need an earth connection - which is why some computers and phone chargers etc have only two connections.

Comment: two prongs are cheaper than three.  there is no other reason. everything is done for maximum profit. if it was up to manufacturers, you would power your toaster by twisting bare wire around binding posts ... lol

Comment: I believe that "US" is unnecessary. Some appliances have 2, some have 3, US is same as the rest of the world. I believe that UK is exceptional here with their use of 3-pronged plugs even when only 2 are used.

Comment: @Agent_L Three pronged plugs are essential in the UK even when the third (ground) prong is not connected to anything, because many sockets have mechanical shutters to prevent kids from poking things into them, etc, which are retracted by the longer third prong to allow the shorter prongs to enter the socket. The third prong may be just a plastic moulding when no electrical connection to it is required.

Comment: USA plug sockets (I've encountered in New York and Orlando, FL) actually spark when you remove the plug and few I've encountered have a switch like modern UK wall sockets. Thing is, we hear of few electrocutions worldwide nowadays so I guess sparkies have untied all the knots and home electricicty is safer than it's ever been. The voltage flow for modern appliances is so low you're at more risk with a small two-pin 9v battery, but that danger of the 120/240v wall socket is always there.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Many appliances in the USA and elsewhere have two-prong plugs because they are "double insulated." The third prong is for ground fault protection except where outlets have been designed with protective shutters on the current-carrying slots that are opened by the ground prong. Double insulation provides very effective ground fault protection that is less expensive for most products.

The fact that the US voltage for domestic wall-plug use is 120 volts offers a small amount of additional safety vs. 220 volts, but that is generally not taken into consideration in US safety standards.

Double insulated or class 2 electrical appliances are products that have been designed in a way so as not to require a safety connection to electrical earth (These products must NOT have a safety connection to Earth).

These products are required to prevent any failure from resulting in dangerous voltage levels becoming exposed causing a shock etc. This must be done without the aid of an earthed metal casing. Ways of achieving this include double layers of insulating material or reinforced insulation protecting any live parts of the fitting.

There are also strict requirements relating to the maximum insulation resistance and leakage to any functional earth or signal connections of such appliances. Products of this type are required to be labelled "Class 2," "Class II,", "double insulated" or bear the double insulation (square in a square) symbol.

The safety of electrical product designs are certified by an independent testing agency such as Underwriters Laboratories (UL) or the Intertek ETL laboratory (originally Edison Testing Laboratory). In order to apply the UL or ETL label, the manufacturer must have product design evaluated and samples tested in the independent laboratory or have their own testing and review results evaluated by the independent laboratory. In either case, they must maintain a contract with the independent testing laboratory that includes periodic, un-announced inspection of their manufacturing facility and its quality assurance procedures.

See the product marking illustration below.

[image]

Comment: That's kind of a backwards non answer though. If it needs a ground it gets three pins, true, but it does not answer the question of why it does not have three pins anyway like other nations on the planet.

Comment: If it doesn't need a ground, the third pin is superfluous. Are you suggesting that having a third pin with no ground wire or a grounded plastic case adds value?

Comment: Yes it can. If you are familiar with UK outlets, the ground pin actually open a trap-door that exposes the other two holes as part of the built in safety features.

Comment: I am not familiar with UK outlets. That is a good feature. US outlets that have shutters that are pushed aside by the prongs are starting to appear, but I don't know how effective or durable they are. I have my doubts. Kids poking forks in outlets is one of the biggest problems with outlets.

Comment: So, with the UK one, they have to open the shutter then they get to poke something in the live compared to other places where it’s just a hole to shove something in... The UK one gives that extra barrier, oh and if you think it’s easy - just try pushing it open...

Comment: @CharlesCowie ya the push aside shutter is an overly complex band-aid type fix on what is a really antiquated system. Unfortunately there seems to be no movement or incentive to revamp the whole system. It's really hard in the USA to legalize such changes too. Wearing seatbelts still is not mandatory in all states.

Comment: @Trevor Look up "europlug" - 2 prongs. UK have their own version of it. Other nations on the planed use 2 prongs whenever 3rd one is not needed. This answer is spot on.

Comment: @Agent_L I'm not saying there is anything wrong with this answer as it accurately answers what dictates when a two or three pin plug is required in the USA according to USA wiring standards. As for the europlug, yes, I know about those, and how they were "accommodated" in UK because of E.U. membership.

Comment: @Trevor, you said it's a "backwards non-answer". That sounds to me like saying there's something wrong with it.

Comment: It's orthogonal discussion but I think many Europlugs have a insulation on top of prong making the exposure of live part much harder (I haven't seen them). Not as good as BS1363 but with NEMA I can just gently push plug to see live metal (and even 'blank' ground would make it so much harder to do it as it would need to be moved too).

Comment: @ThePhoton I said "kind of"

Comment: @Trevor, Okay it sounds like you kind of thing there's something wrong with the answer.

Comment: @ThePhoton no I just meant the answer answers why/when you don't need it, not why you don't have it anyway. Hence the "kind of" ;)

Comment: @Trevor I felt I answered what was directly asked, but didn't cover what might have been implied or of additional interest. I didn't feel the need to object to the comment, particularly in light of the additional information you provided. You are wrong about seat belt laws. The feds withhold state highway money from states without such laws. However cops in many states can't pull you over if that is the only violation.

Comment: YUp there is nothing wrong with your answer, and I up-voted it originally, my comment was more of an adjunct... Kinda wish I'd kept my trap shut now LOL. I believe New Hampshire is still holding out on the seatbelt law... but the other persuasive technique is interesting.

Comment: @Trevor It's Europe and Japan's fault that you don't use ground, not the US. To make a product that can be sold in continental Europe, you either make it Europlug, which doesn't accommodate a ground, so you have to double insulate, or you release 4 versions (Schuko/French, Swiss, Danish, Italian).  Another factor is Japan. Until very recently their plugs did not have a ground plug! At best they provided a ground screw which you use a spade connector on. Double insulating isn't that much more expensive if the product has a plastic case.

Comment: @Trevor They were not "accomodated" in UK. UK has own standard of 2-prong plug ("shaver plug") which appears similar but is incompatible with the Europlug due to slightly thicker prongs. It dates back to 1970s, EU membership has nothing to do here, it's just UK being different for the sake of being different.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka I believe that insulated prongs are an actual requirement on Europlug.

Comment: @Agent_L yes I remember, but that's a tangent to the question. Somehow I opened a can of worms LOL.

Answer (score 17):

I think your question is based on misconceptions.

> For example all BS 1363 plugs have one

BS1363 plugs always have a pin in the earth position to operate the shutter mecahnism and to enforce polarity. However on some non-rewirable plugs and wall warts this pin is made of plastic (reffered to in the BS1363 standard as an "insulated shutter opening device"). Even when the pin is present and made of metal it may not actually be connected to anything.

> Also CEE 7/7 have ground connections and while CEE 7/16 exists it is not used for high-power appliances

There is also CEE 7/17 for high power non-earthed appliances, though i'm not sure how common it is.

> such as computers.

In my experiance desktop PCs always have an earth connection. I will admit I haven't spend a whole lot of time in america but image searches for desktop PC power cord show a bunch of grounded amerian plugs and no ungrounded ones.

Laptops tend to be more variable, years ago they all used the two-prong figure 8 inlet but an increasing number seem to have moved towards the 3-pin cloverleaf inlet.

Small power supplies for phones and tablets generaly don't have an earth connection. Again from what I have seen this is true on both sides of the pond.

Ultimately the desicion whether to have an earth connection or not comes down to whether it is more economical to add the earth connection or to meet the class 2 insulation/leakage standards.

I do get the impression that the US used class 0 appliances (which are not "single fault safe) for longer than other countries did but modern stuff will almost certainly be class 1 (single fault safety provided by earthing) or 2 (single fault safety provided by "double or reinforced insulation").

Comment: "In my experiance desktop PCs always have an earth connection. I will admit I haven't spend a whole lot of time in america but image searches for desktop PC power cord show a bunch of grounded amerian plugs and no ungrounded ones." I think you're right. My bad.

Comment: CEE 7/17 is quite common, e.g. for hair dryers or vacuum cleaners

Comment: I've lived in the US my whole life, and from the earliest IBM PC (you know, the one with an 8088 in it), desktop machines have all had grounded, 3-prong plugs. Many laptops don't, but I believe that grounded plugs are becoming more common. Sadly, I don't recall if the Apple ][ had a grounded plug or not, though [this supply](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-IIgs-NEW-200Watt-Power-supply-TESTED/142557379738?hash=item213114fc9a:g:dA8AAOSwZqZZ9qf5) for a ][gs shows a grounded plug.

Comment: PC plugs will *always* have an earth pin, because the PSU has an earth pin, and [these things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320#C14) need to connect the one to the other.

Comment: @Kevin Outside of the U.S., the wall sockets in many countries don't even have a third pin. All desktops I've encountered in the U.S. have a ground pin, though.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka: 2-prong is not unheard of for laptop power supplies (there are some of each), but desktop/server PC power cords are universally 3-prong here in Canada.  Typically so are monitor power cords.

Answer (score 15):

Mostly cost... the two pin things are cheap as dirt. Three prongs are harder to make so cost more.

As such, if the appliance does not need a ground, they go with the two pin job.

There is no dictated standard in North America that a plug on the end of the cord MUST have three pins regardless of insulation type.

Further, there are countless legacy outlets that have no hole to plug the ground pin into, even in relatively modern buildings. So adding the third pin can actually increase your product return numbers and reduce your market share.

The North American outlet system is rather old. Plugs never seem to fit right and it is really easy to touch the live pins while inserting and removing the plug from the outlet. They also contain no ground pin activated safety features.

On UK receptacles the ground pin opens a protection shutter on the power pins whether the ground is wired up or not. To reduce cost, some "double insulated" appliances have a dummy plastic ground pin on the plug.

[image]

Notice also on the plug that the live and neutral pins have an insulated length on them. The pins do not become live until the metal part is fully inside the receptacle.

[image]

Much safer and more reliable than this thing....

[image]

Electrically, three prong plugs (two power pins and ground) are only electrically required for devices that need to be earth grounded.

Many if not most small domestic appliances, tools, and other systems, are double insulated, that is, insulated in such a way that two faults must occur in the insulation before the user is exposed to lethal voltages. The fact that the customer can quite easily kill themselves while plugging it in, seems to be covered by an S.E.P. field. *( Somebody Else's Problem. )*

The current mechanical nature of the aging North American plug itself, means that, unlike in other countries like the UK, there is NO safety benefit or socket feature that would add value to retaining the ground pin, or a dummy ground pin, when not needed electrically.

Costs therefore dictate that the smaller two pin plug be used when no grounding is required. Costs also dictate that the system is not going to get upgraded any time soon to include better, safer, plugs and outlets.

Comment: I have to say, that the mains plugs are one of the few things we do differently here in the UK that is better than the rest of the world. It is by far the most robust and safe system I've come across in my travels around the world. Mainland Europe also has the option of a two pin mains plug; their mains systems gives me the willies, not quite as much as the US one though!

Comment: In the USA, UL standards require three-prong plugs for appliances that are not double insulated. The standard is not dictated, but there are hoards of lawyers eager to sue if someone is injured by a faulty appliance. That is a very strong incentive. Three-prong outlets have been required for new construction since about 1960. Local codes require outlets to be converted to three-prong if major renovation is done. The lack of three-prong plugs decreases the value of a property. However, there are still a lot of them around. The prevalence of double insulated products mitigates that somewhat.

Comment: @DiBosco yes I have to agree with you. When they redid the standards in the UK to switch from the old odd-sized round pin outlets to the uniform square pin jobs they really thought it out well. In addition to the already mentioned features, local fusing on outlet and plug and switched outlets make it a far better system and it is mechanically much more robust. The only down side, unfortunately, is it is not cheap.

Comment: @Trevor: I like the idea of localized circuit protection, but since plugs tend to outnumber receptacles (people don't use all their appliances at once) I would think that having circuit breakers in receptacles would be better than having fuses in plugs.  My understanding is that BS1633 uses just 13A and 2.5A fuses, which could be accommodated by having high-current outlets include separate holes for 13A-sensed line and 2.5A-sensed line (the same interrupter mechanism could cut power to both).  Low-current extension leads could have receptacles designed for low current only.

Comment: @Trevor - at < £1.50 per outlet and < £0.50 per plug, it's a cost I'm willing to accept.

Comment: "Notice also on the plug that the live and neutral pins have an insulated length on them. The pins do not become live until the metal part is fully inside the receptacle." you don't need to remind me how I miss BS 1363. With NEMA I have seen exposure of live prongs way too often compared to BS 1363/CEE 7/16...

Comment: @Trevor, local fusing on UK plugs is because of that silly ring main system they use.

Comment: @Mark it is not that so much, which I would argue is not that silly, but because plugging your 1A beside lamp into a circuit that is good for 15A can mean the lamp/wiring could seriously overheat in a fault condition without ever blowing the main fuse.

Comment: @Mark that and it only isolates what is plugged in, not the whole circuit.

Comment: Just FYI there is a bit of a vibe in this question, your comments, and especially this answer, that makes it seem like your whole point here was just to criticize approximately half of American power cables. I wonder how you'll feel to learn that I have often seen people actually cut the third pin off of cords that have them, even though that leaves the device they plug in dangerously ungrounded, because they want to be able to plug it into a two-prong receptacle or (more likely) a two-prong extension cord. Americans love the freedom to be dangerous, I guess.

Comment: @ToddWilcox no real vibe, just a commentary. I live here too, and use the things daily. Just as an engineer I find it ironic and odd, and just a bit comical, that we spend so much time making products pass safety tests and get certifications, only to attach that bendy plug on the end of the wire.

Comment: My point was, commentary is not what Stack Exchange is for. Everything in this answer after "Personally..." does nothing to answer the question.

Comment: @ToddWilcox on the contrary, we, the developers know the plug system is dangerous, but the costs of the alternative, and the costs to change the system, dictate we do it anyway. That, ethical paradox, is part of this answer.

Comment: People who live in houses with two-prong outlets know how to deal with them (though, the ways in which they choose to deal with them is not always safe - cutting off the ground pin or using an "adapter" without actually doing anything with the provided ground connection tab, for example), I doubt it'd cause them them not buy or return a product in significant numbers.

Comment: The Electrical Safety Foundation International (ESFI) claims that Tamper Resistant Receptacles (TRR) have been required by the National Electrical Code since 2008.  However, I have seen many homes built after that which lack them.
Source: https://www.esfi.org/resource/what-is-a-tamper-resistant-receptacle-538